# What type of control system to use for a ultrasonic cleaner transducer

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, ultrasound

I got an ultrasonic cleaner transducer that needs 60 W at 40 kHz and I am trying to drive it however since we need amplification I was not sure which board to use.
My main question is what is the difference between these 2 board designs:
[image]

and

[image]

Comment: The second circuit will never provide 60 W and has no osscillator.

Comment: yeah but generally do ultrasonic cleaner boards work in the same way to the circuit with the black background ?